# counting groups which contain an element with a certain attribute

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table containing 3 values

```
CREATE TABLE x (
start      integer NOT NULL,
end        integer NOT NULL,
random     integer NOT NULL);
```

I want to count the amount of groups (`GROUP BY start,end`) that contain at least one element with `random > 42` but are bigger than one element. But as far as I know `HAVING` can only be used with aggregate functions.

My current attempt:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
SELECT count(*) FROM routes 
GROUP BY start,end 
HAVING random > 42 
AND count(*) > 1);
```

results in

> no such column: random

**What would be the most efficient way to solve this problem?**

Comment: sorry for the confusion I forgot to mention that the groups also have to contain more than one element to be of interest. I did edit it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM (SELECT SUM(case when random > 42 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt 
       FROM routes  
       GROUP BY start,end
       HAVING count(*) > 1) as t
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: close, but the where is done before the having thus you'd still count groups which might contain only one element

Comment: changed a little bit to select only groups which contain more than 1 element

Answer (score 0):

Include the condition in your aggregate function itself like below

```
SELECT count(case when random > 42 then 1 else 0 end) as computed_column
FROM routes 
GROUP BY start, end;
```

Your query is bit weird, it can be re-written like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT count(*) as Count_Route
FROM routes 
WHERE random > 42 
GROUP BY start, end 
HAVING count(*) > 1
) XXX;
```